# c# String Length Event

Tags: c#

Basically I want to launch an event when a string reaches a specific length.

I have a Static String

```
Static String  _Info;
```

So i have My Delegate that has an integer as a Parameter !

```
public Delegate void ReachLengthHandler(int Length);
```

and My event :

```
public event ReachLengthHandler ReachLengthEvent;
```

And a Method that Keep addingSome informations to that string :

```
    public void AddInfo()
    {
     new Thread(() =>
    {
     while(true)
     _Info += ""; //Basically add the inputs of the user here ! 
     if (_Info.Length > 500)
      {
       if (ReachLengthEvent != null)
          ReachLengthEvent(_Info.Length);
      }
    }).Start();

    }
```

Do you think its the right way to do this event or there are any cleaner ways ?

**EDIT :** 
I want this event because I want to save this string in a Database table row so I don't want to expand the possible size of a row !

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on codereview

Comment: What do you do with this event? Can you show an example?

Comment: Why not wrap `_Info` in a property and have it fire a real event when the string is updated.

Comment: @Scott Chamberlain its what i thought about !

Comment: @αNerd I want when the string hit a specific length to be saved in a Db table so i don't want to overextand the possible saving size in a row

Comment: @KeithNicholas - no it doesn't. belong there.

Comment: _because I want to save this string in a Database table row so I don't want ..._ - look into proper/standard Validation approaches. You don't need (want) an event, and you don't want it to be static. Ypu do want a property (not a field).

Comment: I don't know how you're getting user input, but I can't imagine that `while(true)` in an anonymous thread is the way to go - don't get me wrong, I use threads like that quite a bit, but it doesn't look elegant at all.

Comment: `while(true)
     _Info += "";` --- it's an infinite loop here isn't it?

Comment: Have you tried looking into a validation approach?

Comment: You should show working code. The fact that there is an infinite loop show that you haven't provide a working example. And by the way appending data to a string like that is very inefficient. You should use a `StringBuilder` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As some pointed out in the comments, you may be trying to solve an instance of the [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/) -- but assuming you're not, you are not approaching things in an object-oriented way, starting with encapsulation.

This could be a start, FWIW:

```
public class MaxLengthEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public MaxLengthEventArgs(string value)
    {
        LastAppended = value;
    }

    public string LastAppended { get; private set; }
}

public delegate void MaxLengthEventHandler(object sender, MaxLengthEventArgs args);

public class StringAccumulator
{
    protected StringBuilder Builder { get; private set; }

    public StringAccumulator(int maxLength)
    {
        if (maxLength < 0)
        {
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("maxLength", "must be positive");
        }
        Builder = new StringBuilder();
        MaxLength = maxLength;
    }

    public StringAccumulator Append(string value)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
        {
            var sofar = value.Length + Builder.Length;
            if (sofar <= MaxLength)
            {
                Builder.Append(value);
                if ((OnMaxLength != null) && (sofar == MaxLength))
                {
                    OnMaxLength(this, new MaxLengthEventArgs(value));
                }
            }
            else
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException("overflow");
            }
        }
        return this;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Builder.ToString();
    }

    public int MaxLength { get; private set; }

    public event MaxLengthEventHandler OnMaxLength;
}

class Program
{
    static void Test(object sender, MaxLengthEventArgs args)
    {
        var acc = (StringAccumulator)sender;
        Console.WriteLine(@"max length ({0}) reached with ""{1}"" : ""{2}""", acc.MaxLength, args.LastAppended, acc.ToString());
    }

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var acc = new StringAccumulator(10);
        try
        {
            acc.OnMaxLength += Test;
            acc.Append("abc");
            acc.Append("def");
            acc.Append("ghij");
            Console.WriteLine();
            acc.Append("ouch...");
            Console.WriteLine("(I won't show)");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex);
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Also, keep in mind that strings in .NET are immutable.

Accumulating them using string concatenation, as you did in

```
_Info += ""
```

... isn't going to scale well (performance-wise).

'HTH,

Comment: Well, if the code must read an exact length and throw an exception otherwise, it does not make much sense to use a `string` as the argument. It should be a `char` instead. **At least, there are a few good tricks there**.

Comment: @Phil1970 maybe I missed / failed with something in this quick shot at it, but no, the intent is to trigger the event if and only if the last call to Append makes the accumulated string's final length exactly equal to MaxLength, or to throw an exception if that last call would cause an overflow (hence the accompanying test, btw). For the OP's interest wrt. the question, my main point was about encapsulation. Of course, one can augment the public interface to Append char-by-char, or int-by-int, etc, as is done in the underlying StringBuilder's overloads.

Answer (score 0):

Usually eventhandler is used with specific signature.

```
public delegate void ReachLengthHandler(object sender, EventArgs args);
class Program
{
    public event ReachLengthHandler handler;

    private const int Threshhold = 500;

    public string Info
    {
        set
        {
            if (value.Length > Threshhold)
            {
                this.OnReachLength(null);
            }
        }
    }

    public void OnReachLength(EventArgs args)
    {
        this.handler?.Invoke(this, args);
    }
}
```

Comment: Never send null arguments for event as it is contrary to what it is expected. If there is no argument, then use `EventArgs.Empty`.